# Excel macro to find a cell in a sheet and copy the entire row in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel sheet with around 50k rows and i need a macro to search for a cell in that sheet and if it finds it to copy the entire row to another sheet, my problem is that the keyword may be on multiple rows so if there are like 4 cells with that keyword i need it to copy all 4 rows and paste them in another sheet

```
Sub saca()

Dim intPasteRow As Integer
intPasteRow = 2
Dim ceva As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim intRow As Integer

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Columns("A:AV").Select
On Error Resume Next
Set ceva = Selection.Find(What:="m762", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
If Not ceva Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddress = ceva.Address
    Do
        Set ceva = Selection.FindNext(ceva).Activate
    Loop While Not ceva Is Nothing And ceva.Address <> FirstAddress
End If

intRow = ActiveCell.Row
Rows(intRow & ":" & intRow).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

So far its searching for "m762" in Sheet2 but it only copies the first row with a "m762" cell instead of selecting all of them...I can't find a way to make it select all rows with "m762" in them

Comment: with `intRow = ActiveCell.Row` you will get just one cell row, so on `Rows(intRow & ":" & intRow).Select` you are just selecting one row What are you trying to do with this code? (I think it should be `Rows(intRow & ":" & intColumn).Select` and `intColumn` should be defined as `intColumn = ActiveCell.Column`. Please, show some sample to get some help.

Comment: i have a sheet with around 50k entries, each row being an entry and each one of them has a "user code" (the "m762" i'm searching for being one of them), i'm trying to search for a user ("m762") and copy all the rows he's present on in another sheet

Comment: You could look into AutoFilter

Comment: @Aceleon... I already understand your question but without some sample, it is difficult to know. For 50k data it will be just easier add one more row that will have a blank when it is not matching with the user and not blank when it is matching, I will filter by blank values, so you just need to copy all the visible data. But it will be a generic answer to a generic question.

Comment: Can "m762" be in one column, in a few columns, or in any column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel macro to search for a keyword and and copy the entire row to another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58693774/excel-macro-to-search-for-a-keyword-and-and-copy-the-entire-row-to-another-sheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not the best or quickest solution, here is a basic `For Loop` macro that will loop through each cell and when the criteria is found, it will copy the row in `Sheet2` to the next empty row in `Sheet1` by setting the values directly from `Sheet2` to `Sheet1`. It will then continue and copy each row where the criteria is found.

```
Dim cel As Range, lRow As Long

    For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:AV" & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If cel.Value = "m762" Then
            lRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow + 1, 1).Resize(, 48).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(cel.Row, 1).Resize(, 48).Value
        End If
    Next cel
```

Comment: this works but it only searches the first ~150 rows...can't seem to make it search all the way down

Comment: Updated, I did not change the second worksheet in the first line to `Sheet2`, so it is using `Sheet1` row count which probably has only 150 rows filled.